# How to get Xamarin Test Cloud Device String

Tags: xamarin, continuous-integration, xamarin-test-cloud

I am trying to use CI along with Xamarin Test Cloud for an automated CI + Execute test scenario using Visual Studio Online.

While creating a new Xamarin Android build definition, it asks to enter a value for Devices, which is quoted as

> The devices string is generated by Xamarin Test Cloud. It can be found as the value of the --devices command line argument of a Test Cloud test run.

Any ideas how can I get this string & from where? 
I'm using UiTest & uploaded the test to Xamarin Test cloud from Visual Studio-> Test Project-> Right Click-> Run in Test cloud

help is appreciated.

Thanks 
ST

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to generate a valid --devices string is to go to https://testcloud.xamarin.com/ and select "New Test Run" which you can go through and select your devices. At the final screen named "Submit your tests to finish", you can then grab the --devices parameter value from the generated `test-cloud.exe` command.